# Error 403 Forbidden still persisting while using url lib (python3) and giving appropriate headers

Tags: python, html, flask, web, urllib

So my code goes something like...

```
from urllib.request import Request,urlopen

url = 'some url'

req = Request(url,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req,timeout=10).read()
```

I also added some more headers according to other suggestions, but the error is still persisting. Also, I cleared the cache from FireFox, so that isn't a problem. 
So why is the error persisting? 
I tried other methods also like
`from requests import get` but the error is still occurring.

This same code was working 1 to 2 day ago, but now its suddenly giving 403 error.
What shall I do so that I get the webpage?

Comment: Sometimes backend developers mess up with status code and use the wrong status code. Maybe they wanted to say that you are not authenticated and you are trying to access a page.

Comment: Also, this same code was working 2 days ago and it suddenly stopped now

Comment: could be that you got blocked. Can you access the URL with your browser?

Comment: Yes I can access it through the browser